# How to incorporate/account for family membership in regression

Tags: regression

Consider the classic regression setting where we want to model Y using some design matrix X. However, let's say that part of the design matrix is a matrix of familial relationships up to some degree of relatedness. For example, let's say there are Z families in the dataset, with many individuals belonging to a single-person family. So this part of the design matrix has Z columns but is very sparse (e.g. many columns are all zeroes but for the single individual that is in that family). However, this cannot just be ignored because there are families with multiple people who also have highly correlated characteristics both in the rest of the design matrix and Y (for example, if Y is a disease, there is a higher chance of people in the same family having the disease).

What are ways to address this so that the effect of belonging to different families is accounted for?

Comment: This is called multilevel modeling.

Comment: would this not run into the same problem if the grouping is sparse? i.e. a large number of groups (say 90%) have a single member.

Comment: You might be able to fit a multilevel model even with 90% of groups having single value, but maybe it would be more suitable to fit a single-level regression with clustered standard errors. See, for instance [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/05/clustered-standard-errors-with-r/) and [this](https://evalf21.classes.andrewheiss.com/example/standard-errors/) resource for R solutions and [this](https://economictheoryblog.com/2017/10/23/clustered-standard-errors-in-stata/) for Stata.